# Hierarchy navigation with Template 10 Hamburger Template

Tags: uwp, template10

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with page hierarchies in an UWP app using Template 10 Hamburger Template.
In the end, I'd like to be able to select the app's main sections over the Hamburger menu items and have some sort of tab selection to navigate through the sections' views and sub-views, changing the available tabs depending of the context I'm currently in.

The sections of the app are fairly complex and should be navigable as well, e.g. I should be able to navigate to the next higher hierarchy using the back button, so I think the tab navigation will have to be based on frame navigation.

How can I manage that the Hamburger menu item of the section I'm currently in stays selected when I navigate through the pages and sub-pages of the section?
Is there an alternative to using the HamburgerButtonInfo's PageType attribute (which binds the selection state of the item to the page that's currently displayed)?

Some Picutres to explain: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emRXJ.png)

Comment: Could you visualize this navigation in some simple image?

Comment: Please check added Image with some explanatory details.

Comment: So the problem is the hamburger menu item's selection state?

Comment: That's what got this question started. But I think the big issue is that I'm trying to figure out a sensible way of implementing an application with multiple hierarchy levels as described in the graphics I uploaded. Is a Pivot adequate or what is the basic approach for this scenario? The machanism behind the selection state of the hamburger menu item points towards working with one page with a Pivot _per hamburger menu item_. On the other hand, if having one page per _tab_ is a good approach, there should be an easy way to set the menu items selected state, that I'm probably missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to highlight a hamburger menu item on a 'subpage' you can do the following:

1. Create a method in your Shell class for selecting the button you want to select in code. In it just set Selected of your HamburgerMenu to the desired HamburgerButtonInfo instance. The PageType must be set to 'null' in order to avoid navigation to the according page.

   ```
   public static HamburgerButtonInfo AButton => Instance.MyButton;
   public void HighlightButton(HamburgerButtonInfo button)
   {
       Type pageType = button.PageType;
       button.PageType = null;
       HamburgerMenu.Selected = button;
       button.PageType = pageType;
   }
   ```
2. In OnNavigatedTo of your page call that method via Shell.Instance.

   ```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       Shell.Instance.HighlightButton(Shell.AButton);
       base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Using Template 10 navigation system, you can pass parameters to the page and subsequently open the correct tab (as shown in the settings page from Hamburger project template).

But when the users changes tab, it will still be the same page and you can't control the back button behavior because changing the pivot doesn't go to the stack (maybe there is a way to force it if you track the `SelectionChanged` event, but I'm not sure).
At the moment you cannot manipulate the BackRequest and manually manipulate the stack if you are on Level 2 because there is a bug that makes it working only with hardware buttons (on phones and mouse back button, it doesn't work clicking the button on the screen).

You could always do how you made the picture:
Level 0 opens up a page, these Level 1 page can contain the link to Level 2 as a different page.

I think the best way to implement it, is to make a custom control that shows the current tree starting from Level 1.
A according to your example it is the first row of the page, the one that shows "Menu Item 1" and "Menu Item 1 > Detail of item X on page 1". 
You can place that control on every page, it's optional because this solution works even without it.

On Level 1 page, you can just navigate to Level 2 page; it will be added to the stack and then when the user hits "back" it will go back to the parent page.

Comment: So the views 1.1 and 1.2 of my example would each be the contents of a PivotItem on a single page (e.g. Level_1_Page).
And navigating to the details of item X would lead to a second page (something like Level_1.1_Page) with its own pivot with three items containing the views 1.1.1, 1.1.2 and 1.1.3 in my example.
From there, the "back" button would lead back to Level_1_Page. Correct?
But still, how do I keep the hamburger menu item selected when I'm on Level_1.1_Page?

Comment: Well, that probably needs a change in Template 10 framework. Template 10 is on GitHub, you can start a discussion there and propose the change in behavior to keep it selected even if it's not on top of the navigation stack.